# Advice for a good solvent for fragrance

Tags: solvents, evaporation

Hi any suggestions for a solvent for aroma oils, that has low evaporation and high diffusivity (low molecular weight and hence spreads well in the air). The solvent should also be soluble in water and should have a low evaporation rate

Comment: 2-butanol? Bpt 99C

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, but 2-butanol is flammable , sorry i forgot to mention this...I am trying to work on home made reed/ wood fragrance diffuser...need something non toxic too...is Dowanol TPM good ...i am not sure if it will diffuse well in the air

Comment: I am not a fragrance chemist but Dowanol is flammable.

Comment: Diffusion of the solvent has nothing to do with carrying the fragrances around. It should even be a con as for high diffusion should (on feeling) go like boiling point, at least from molecular mass only. Either you do not want naked fragrances at the beginning, or if so, diffusion of the solvent doesn't count. Rather you need a special size of droplets. It seems to me that you should reproduce what big names or artisans do, rather than starting your own recipes. Many of your requirements won't have easy conciliatory solutions.